# How to call a Jquery function starting with $ from outside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function like below

```
var func = $(function add(){

});
```

I have the below the JS code to call the function

```
function rest(){
     //try 1
     var fun = new func();
     fun.add(); 
     //try 2
     add();
 }
```

But both of the times I am getting errors only. How to call them properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `add` isn't a callable function. It's a function that gets called when the DOM is ready. It's a shorthand for `$(document).ready(fn)` where `fn` is `add` in your case.

One way you can do it is just declare it inside that callback instead.

```
$(function(){

  function add(){...}

  function rest(){...}

});
```

This also avoids spawning globals which is bad practice. If you're calling them from elements, consider binding event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You use fn.extend or just add to the object directly.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    add: function(){}
});
$(element).add();
//or
$.add = function(){};
$.add();
```